# Quando eu inicio uma sessão no WordPress, o layout do template quebra

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo um template WordPress para um cliente, porem quando eu logo no wp-admin, ai o slide show não funciona e o *layout* quebra, fica tudo como se tivesse erro de CSS.

Porém se eu abrir em guia anônima no navegador, ele abre normal e lindo!

Será que tem alguma coisa a ver com a sessão criada quando se loga?

Comment: Talvez exista configurações personalizadas em seu usuário, tente criar um novo usuário e faça login com este usuário.

Comment: Criei outro usuário porem não deu certo!

Comment: Então é uma configuração relacionada aos usuários. Tenta comparar o código HTML do usuário logado e o não logado. Versifica se não está sendo adicionado algo a mais.

Answer (score 3):

Quando o usuário está logado, aparece o menu WP Admin (*default* do WordPress) que acrescenta as seguintes folhas de estilo:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css?ver=4.1.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css?ver=4.1.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

E também acrescenta um script e este `div` no final do HTML:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.js?ver=4.1.8'></script>
<div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq nojs" role="navigation">
```

Pode-se desabilitar essa barra individualmente no perfil de cada usuário ou usar esta linha de código para desabilitar geral:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Normalmente recomendo colocar esse tipo de código num plugin personalizado, mas como é tão simples pode ser colado no arquivo `functions.php` do seu theme.

Se não for isso, pode ser algum plugin que só funciona quando o usuário está logado, para confirmar desligue todos os plugins e confira se o erro continua.

Comment: Exatamente isso que imaginei :D, boa!